# cannot get post data from a file input

Tags: javascript, php, oracle

i dont know why this is not working...the post in not contain any data...
so there is any others thing that i should consider before using this like setting in php or what?

```
<html lang="en">
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="gambaqprocess.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
                            <label>file attachment</label> 
                                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"
                            cols="10" wrap="soft" placeholder="" rows="5" value=""></input>
                            </div>


                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="action"
                                value="view">Add</button>
                                </form>
                                    </body>
                                </html>
```

then this is the process

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['file']))
{
    $file=$_files['file'];
    print_r($file);
    $filename=$_files['file']['name'];
    print_r($file);

}else
    echo'cannot get post data';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here only file element is in the form, that's why `$_POST` will not contain any data. Files posted in form can be retrieved from `$_FILES` variable. So you should try:

```
if(isset($_FILES['file']))
```

Instead of

```
if(isset($_POST['file']))
```